# iOS Swift: saving an array of custom classes

Tags: ios, arrays, serialization, swift

I am new to programming. I am making a little database program for iOS in swift.

I have a person class:

```
class Person : NSObject {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String

    init (firstName : String, lastName : String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

I declare an array of the class at the top of my view controller:

```
    var peopleArray = [Person]()
```

I then fill the array by declaring some sample users and append it to the array:

```
    var nateB = Person(firstName: "Nate", lastName: "Birkholz")
    var nateC = Person(firstName: "Nate", lastName: "Carson")
    var nateD = Person(firstName: "Nate", lastName: "Donnelly")
    self.peopleArray.append(nateB)
    self.peopleArray.append(nateC)
    self.peopleArray.append(nateD)
```

I then try to save the data to a plist file:

```
        let fileManager = (NSFileManager.defaultManager())
        let directorys : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

        if (directorys != nil){
            let directories:[String] = directorys!;
            let pathToFile = directories[0]; //documents directory
            let plistfile = "PeopleArray.plist"
            let plistpath = pathToFile.stringByAppendingPathComponent(plistfile);

            if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(plistpath){ 

                println("Declaring cocoaArray")
                var cocoaArray : NSArray = peopleArray
                cocoaArray.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true)
            println("I wrote an array to the file at\n\n\(plistpath)")
            }
```

The plist file isn't created, it silently fails to create and the function completes as if it had. Any thoughts?

The obscure compatibility processes of the swift data types and data structures with the cocoa classes is frustrating to me. I just want to save a danged file. I also can't use the "append" function if I declare my array as an NSArray, nor can I += an item into the array...

**Update**:

I added the following functions to my Person class:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(firstName, forKey:"firstName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(lastName, forKey:"lastName")
}

init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    self.firstName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as String
    self.lastName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("lasName") as String
}
```

Saving the file is now:

```
let fileManager = (NSFileManager.defaultManager())
        let directorys : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

        println("value of directorys is \(directorys)")

        if (directorys != nil){
            let directories:[String] = directorys!;
            let pathToFile = directories[0]; //documents directory

            let plistfile = "PeopleArray.plist"
            let plistpath = pathToFile.stringByAppendingPathComponent(plistfile);

            if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(plistpath){  //writing Plist file

                self.createInitialPeople()

                println("Declaring cocoaArray")
                var cocoaArray : NSArray = [NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(peopleArray)]
                println("writing to path")
                cocoaArray.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true)
                let tellMe = cocoaArray.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true)
                println("Return of write is \(tellMe)")
            }
```

A Plist file with inscrutable data is created.

I close the app and start it again, i then try too load the file:

```
         else {            //Reading Plist file
            println("\n\nPlist file found at \(plistpath)")

            let cocoaArray = NSMutableArray.arrayWithContentsOfFile(plistpath)

            peopleArray = cocoaArray as Array
        }
    }
```

And I fail because I cannot downcast "AnyObject is not identical to 'Person'. I have tried downcasting it in several ways and just cannot do so successfully. This is really frustrating.

Comment: Use NSMutableArray if you need an array you can modify.

Comment: How do you know the file was not created?  Is it possible you aren't looking in the right place?

Comment: If I declare it as NSMUtableArray I lose access to a number of features of Swift Arrays that I am using elsewhere, forcing me to refactor everything and actually go find new ways to do things as I am at this  point more familiar with Swift than Objective C. And yes, the file is definitely not created. I go to the address I generated with the println() call and there is nothing there. If I save an array of strings, it works. Something about the way it is attempting to save the array of class instances causes it to fail silently. A plist is just a keyed xml file, it shouldn't be too hard, right?

Comment: its possibly going to be an overlooked post now that Swift 2 is in the wild, but if you copy/paste the output of println("\n\nPlist file found at \(plistpath)") into your Finder>Go>Go To Folder, or [ Shift-Command-G ] , it should immediately show the Plist in the Application>LongWindedAlphaNumerics>Documents path

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, the root cause is `[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]` only supports certain data types. You can check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#jumpTo_70).

If you print out the return code from  `cocoaArray.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true)`, you will see it is set to `False`.

To overcome this restriction, you need to

1) implement a encode function in your `Person` class

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(firstName, forKey:"firstName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(lastName, forKey:"lastName")
}
```

2) Convert the elements in your array into `NSData`, e.g.

```
   var cocoaArray : NSArray = [NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(nateB)]
```

At the end, you will also need a decode function in the `Person` class to support reading them back from a plist file

Comment: Much obliged, this gives me a proper starting point for learning more. I wish i was better able ti find these sorts of things on my own, I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @NateBirkholz No worries. If you think the solution addresses your problem, please upvote and accept. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to up vote yet. I'm working on adding it too the code now to be sure it resolves everything. To check the return code from cocoaArray.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true) I just added a line to send that to a variable and then println the variable, is that the best way?

Comment: @NateBirkholz Yeah, that's good enough. It is what I did:            let res = cocoaArray.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true)
            println("I wrote an array to the file at \\(plistpath) with res \\(res)")

Comment: I'm zeroing in, I think. I don't know the protocols here for giving more info. Do I edit my original question?

Comment: I have a feeling it should become a second question. Your current issue differs very much from your original question.

Comment: Did you solve this?  How would it work for arrays of structs?

Answer (score 12):

After you added the following functions to your Person class:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(firstName, forKey:"firstName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(lastName, forKey:"lastName")
}


init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    self.firstName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstName") as String
    self.lastName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("lasName") as String
}
```

**You should use 【NSKeyedArchiver】 and 【NSKeyedUnarchiver】 to store and fetch the array.**

Thanks **@Anthony Kong**.

His answer helps a lot, but I think the following codes can really solve the problem.

TO STORE THE ARRAY IN PLIST

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true)
let path: AnyObject = paths[0]
let arrPath = path.stringByAppendingString("/array.plist")
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(peopleArray, toFile: arrPath)
```

TO FETCH THE ARRAY FORM PLIST

```
if let tempArr: [Person] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(arrPath) as? [Person] {
    peopleArray = tempArr
}
```