# Save NSMutableArray with Class to Plist File in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, plist

Hey I just want to save my NSMutableArray with Class. But When i try to read the file my app getting crush. I found [this](https://gist.github.com/frozzare/d4a9bbeb39e5425e7c26) and i tried to convert for NSMutableArray. Now I cant figure out what can i do.

My Class:

```
class Customer {
    var name = String()
    var email = String()
    var phoneNumber = Int()
    var bAdd = String()
    var bAdd2 = String()
    var sAdd = String()
    var sAdd2 = String()

    init(name: String, email: String, phoneNumber: Int, bAdd: String, bAdd2: String, sAdd: String, sAdd2: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.bAdd = bAdd
        self.bAdd2 = bAdd2
        self.sAdd = sAdd
        self.sAdd2 = sAdd2
    }

    class func exists (path: String) -> Bool {
        return NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)
    }

    class func read (path: String) -> NSMutableArray? {
        if Customer.exists(path) {
            return NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)!
        }
        return nil
    }

    class func write (path: String, content: NSMutableArray) -> Bool {
        return content.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

My Array:

```
var ItemData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

and My Read Code:

```
 let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
 let customerPath = documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Test.plist")

    ItemData = Customer.read(customerPath)!
```

When i tried to read im gettin this crash:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>       (lldb)

Any Advice?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is your problem? What happens / does not happen?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Did you try searching for "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"? Do you know what that means? Which value was being force-unwrapped, and why?

Comment: If you're not sure, you might start by removing all `!` operators from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine except that you do not actually have anything to read from in the beginning, therefore `Customer.read(customerPath)` returns nil, which you try to unwrap - therefore the error.

If you just write something beforehand and then try to read it again like this, everything works fine.

```
ItemData.addObject("aisnd")
Customer.write(customerPath, content: ItemData)
ItemData = Customer.read(customerPath)!
```

Of course that is not the way to actually do it, because it is normal that you don't have anything present in the beginning. Therefore you have to check wether or not the `read` function actually returns something useful:

```
var ItemData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
if let item = Customer.read(customerPath) {
    ItemData = item
} else {
    print("no value found")
}
```

Final note 1 because playground suggested it: remove the `!` from the `as! String`. Final note 2: don't start variable names uppercase, the variable should be called `itemData`.

**Edit**
To write `Customer` objects you have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345076/ios-swift-saving-an-array-of-custom-classes).

Comment: I tried to save before but it still same. I'm basically saving like this Customer.write(customerPath, content: ItemData) . But it doesnt work? Actually my write code is incorrect?

Comment: @SalihÇiftçi I can assure you 100% that your code works, I just pasted it in playground and played around with it, both read and write work.

Comment: Okey then. Why is it not working in project? Why could it be?

Comment: @SalihÇiftçi try a different file name, you might have screwed up the `Test.plist` contents because of previous write attempts.

Comment: I did. Even I reset the simulator.

Comment: When i save without init its work. But with init it doesnt.

Comment: @SalihÇiftçi what init?

Comment: in my Class? like this itemData.addObject(Customer(name: "Hey!", email: "mail@mail", phoneNumber: 1, bAdd: "a", bAdd2: "b", sAdd: "c", sAdd2: "d"))

Comment: @SalihÇiftçi well, that is an entirely different story, writing custom objects to files is not as easy as that... take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345076/ios-swift-saving-an-array-of-custom-classes